# No implicits found for parameter evidence

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a line of code in a scala app that takes a dataframe with one column and two rows, and assigns them to variables `start` and `end`:

```
val Array(start, end) = datesInt.map(_.getInt(0)).collect()
```

This code works fine when run in a REPL, but when I try to put the same line in a scala object in Intellij, it inserts a grey `(?: Encoder[Int])` before the `.collect()` statement, and show an inline error `No implicits found for parameter evidence$6: Encoder[Int]`

I'm pretty new to scala and I'm not sure how to resolve this.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Spark needs to know how to serialize JVM types to send them from workers to the master. In some cases they can be automatically generated and for some types there are explicit implementations written by Spark devs. In this case you can implicitly pass them. If your `SparkSession` is named `spark` then you miss following line:

```
import spark.implicits._
```

As you are new to Scala: implicits are parameters that you don't have to explicitly pass. In your example `map` function requires `Encoder[Int]`. By adding this import, it is going to be included in the scope and thus passed automatically to `map` function.

Check [Scala documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-parameters.html) to learn more.

Comment: thanks! In IntelliJ I needed to add a fields to a class: `var spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()` or sth similar, just to have this import working. I placed the import *inside the method*.